Derived Gtk::DrawingArea widget is not loaded from Glade builder file correctly
I am working on an embedded Linux project using gtk/gtkmm 3. I use Glade builder files to define the UI and load them during program runtime. That works fine.
Now I need a custom circular progress widget, so a derived a class from Gtk::DrawingArea as suggested in the gtkmm documentation.
// MyCircularProgress.hpp
class MyCircularProgress : public Gtk::DrawingArea
{
public:
  MyCircularProgress();
  MyCircularProgress(GtkDrawingArea* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refBuilder);
  virtual ~MyCircularProgress();
  
protected:

  bool on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr) override;
};

// MyCircularProgress.cpp
#include "CircularProgress.hpp"

MyCircularProgress::MyCircularProgress() :
// To register custom properties, you must register a custom GType.  If
// you don't know what that means, don't worry, just remember to add
// this Glib::ObjectBase constructor call to your class' constructor.
// The GType name will be gtkmm__CustomObject_MyCircularProgress.
  Glib::ObjectBase("MyCircularProgress")
{
}

MyCircularProgress::MyCircularProgress(GtkDrawingArea* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refBuilder) :
// To register custom properties, you must register a custom GType.  If
// you don't know what that means, don't worry, just remember to add
// this Glib::ObjectBase constructor call to your class' constructor.
// The GType name will be gtkmm__CustomObject_MyCircularProgress.
    Glib::ObjectBase("MyCircularProgress"),
    Gtk::DrawingArea(cobject)
{
}

MyCircularProgress::~MyCircularProgress()
{
}

bool MyCircularProgress::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)
{
  Gtk::Allocation allocation = get_allocation();
  const int width = allocation.get_width();
  const int height = allocation.get_height();

  cr->set_source_rgb(0.8, 0.0, 0.0);
  cr->rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
  cr->fill();

  return true;
}

The corresponding glade file derived.glade:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="wnd_app">
    <property name="name">wnd_app</property>
    <property name="width_request">480</property>
    <property name="height_request">320</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="baseline_position">top</property>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child type="center">
          <object class="gtkmm__CustomObject_MyCircularProgress" id="draw_progress">
            <property name="width_request">200</property>
            <property name="height_request">200</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="valign">start</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>

In the main.cpp I registered the new C++ wrapper before using the builder.
#include <vector>
#include "CircularProgress.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

template <class T>
std::string
type_name()
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type TR;
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> own
           (
#ifndef _MSC_VER
                abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(TR).name(), nullptr,
                                           nullptr, nullptr),
#else
                nullptr,
#endif
                std::free
           );
    std::string r = own != nullptr ? own.get() : typeid(TR).name();
    if (std::is_const<TR>::value)
        r += " const";
    if (std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
        r += " volatile";
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&";
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&&";
    return r;
}

// Not really used anywhere, but force an instance to be created.
MyCircularProgress* my_global_accessible_progress = nullptr;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "my.circularprogress");

  // Create a dummy instance before the call to refBuilder->add_from_file().
  // This creation registers DerivedButton's class in the GType system.
  my_global_accessible_progress = new MyCircularProgress();

  //Load the Glade file and instantiate its widgets:
  auto refBuilder = Gtk::Builder::create();
  try
  {
    refBuilder->add_from_file("derived.glade");
  }
  catch(const Glib::FileError& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << "FileError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  catch(const Glib::MarkupError& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << "MarkupError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  catch(const Gtk::BuilderError& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << "BuilderError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  Gtk::ApplicationWindow* pWnd = nullptr;
  refBuilder->get_widget("wnd_app", pWnd);

  if(pWnd)
  {
    auto objects = refBuilder->get_objects();

    for(auto item : objects)
    {
      std::cout << typeid(item).name() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_name<decltype(item)>() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "----------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }

    MyCircularProgress* pProgress;
    refBuilder->get_widget_derived("draw_progress", pProgress);
    if(pProgress)
    {
      std::cout << "MyCircularProgress name: " << pProgress->get_name() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_name<decltype(pProgress)>() << std::endl;
    }

    Gtk::DrawingArea* pDraw;
    refBuilder->get_widget("draw_progress", pDraw);
    if(pDraw)
    {
      std::cout << "Gtk::DrawingArea name: " << pDraw->get_name() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_name<decltype(pDraw)>() << std::endl;
    }

    app->run(*pWnd);
  }

  delete pWnd;
  delete my_global_accessible_progress;

  return 0;
}

When I start the program and load the UI using the builder, the derived class MyCircularProgress is not instantiated. There is no error output to the console, but the expected constructor MyCircularProgress(GtkDrawingArea* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refBuilder) is not called.
When I try to get the MyCircularProgress instance from the builder using:
MyCircularProgress* pProgress;
refBuilder->get_widget_derived("draw_progress", pProgress);

I get the following error message on the console:
Gtk::Builder::get_widget_derived(): dynamic_cast<> failed. An existing C++ instance, of a different type, seems to exist.
When I try to get the base class instance from the builder using:
Gtk::DrawingArea* pDraw;
refBuilder->get_widget("draw_progress", pDraw);

Then I get a valid pointer.
Has anybody an idea, what's wrong? The Gtk builder seems to create the correct base class Gtk::DrawingArea of the derived C++ class MyCircularProgress, but does not assign it correctly.

Could you please provide a minimal and reproducible example please?

I have updated the question accordingly. On the target system, Gtk+ 3.24 is installed.

This line is the problem:
auto objects = refBuilder->get_objects();

I gets all the objects constructed by the builder. In your case, it gets your derived widget as a Gtk::DrawingArea (this is why the constructor for this type is called). When you try to get the same widget again as another type, it fails.
Note: If you had constructed a minimal example, you would for sure have found this easily.

Many thank's for the suggestion, it works now. This piece of code was inserted during the problem search to see the types of the created objects. I would not have expected this behavior. I expected, that the registered derived C++ type would be returned, especially after the explicit GType registration, without influence to the following calls.

My pleasure. If it works for you, could you please accept the answer?

Of course, accepted, thanks again.
